# Flutter custom clipper with stack not working correctly

Tags: dart, flutter, flutter-layout

I really interested with flutter, and currently I'm trying to create a custom clipper with clipPart widget. but it's seems not working correctly.

here is my code

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

void main() => runApp(MaterialApp(
  title: "My App",
  home: HomePage(),
  debugShowCheckedModeBanner: false,
));

class HomePage extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      body: Column(
        children: <Widget>[
          Container(
            alignment: Alignment.topCenter,
            color: Colors.teal,
            child: HomeScreenTop(),
          )
        ],
      ),
    );
  }
}

class HomeScreenTop extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _HomeScreenTopState createState() => _HomeScreenTopState();
}

class _HomeScreenTopState extends State<HomeScreenTop> {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Stack(
      textDirection: TextDirection.ltr,
      children: <Widget>[
        Align(
          alignment: Alignment.topCenter,
          child: WaveContainer(),
        ),
      ],
    );
  }
}

class WaveContainer extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return ClipPath(
      clipper: CustomShapeClipper(),
      clipBehavior: Clip.antiAlias,
      child: Container(
        width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width,
        height: 400.0,
        color: Colors.orange,
      ),
    );
  }
}

class CustomShapeClipper extends CustomClipper<Path> {
  @override
  getClip(Size size) {
    print(size.height);
    final Path path =Path();
    path.lineTo(size.width / 2, size.height);
    path.lineTo(size.width,  0);

    path.close();
    return path;
  }

  @override
  bool shouldReclip(CustomClipper oldClipper) => true;

}
```

what I want to do is, create a triangle from top to bottom, as I know from the tutorial, Offset of `x = 0` and `y = 0` should be pointing to `left-top` corner of the page. So if create like this

```
path.lineTo(size.width / 2, size.height);
path.lineTo(size.width,  0);
```

the path should be drawing from `left-top` to `middle-down` to `right-top` and back to `left-top`
[image: expected result]

But what I've got when I try the code is like this
[image: current issue]

And, the stack is not working.. the triangle should isolated inside the container but why the custom clipper can exceed the bottom container??

I really confuse, Please help

Comment: I simply copy pasted your code and it gives me  https://imgur.com/oUwhZgT

Comment: @Ryosuke That is exactly what I expected... It's weird.. What flutter version that you use?

Comment: `Flutter 1.3.10-pre.5 • channel master • https://github.com/flutter/flutter.git
Framework • revision ddee4f716c (10 days ago) • 2019-03-10 23:22:28 -0400
Engine • revision 0d2cf5857b
Tools • Dart 2.2.1 (build 2.2.1-dev.1.0 2fb6cd9f5f)`

Comment: It's weird... I try in iOS emulator and working well.. Thanks @Ryosuke

Comment: @Ryosuke I did nothing....

Answer (score 0):

Solved by change the emulator from Genymotion to iOS IphoneX emulator. Don't know why it show different behaviour between iOS and android, but I think iOS emulator is the right one..